# Excel formulae query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, formulas

I have a data sheet and have to create a report which is based on multiple conditions based on data. Attaching an image of the Data sheet and another sheer which is a report sheet.

**Data Sheet:**

[image]

**Report Sheet:**

[image]

**Question:** In the report sheet, in column A I have unique types and in column B I want the total count of the objects based on type and color. So presently I want total count of Orange fruit and Orange vegetable. i.e. B3 will have 2 as the value and B4 will be 1.

I tried the following formulae, but I am getting 0 in B3:

```
=COUNT(IF((Data!$A$2:Data!$A$7=A3 * Data!$B$2:Data!$B$7=“Orange”),Data!$C$2:Data!$C$7))
```

Is the condition I am using inside IF incorrect?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do.  Maybe this countif function might help-> http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx

Comment: I am basically trying to do an AND operation here. If fruit AND orange, then true on each row and at the end I get the count i.e. for fruit and orange combination in my data sheet, row 2 is true so 10 is in, row 3 is false, row 4 is true and row 5,6,7 are false. Hence 10+20 should give me 30 in B3 of my report sheet.

Comment: Am sorry my result should be 2 and 1, I mixed up SUM and count. I will update the question. But basically I am here to check my AND not working in the condition inside the IF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the total, you are looking for `SUM` not `COUNT`.

Especially `SUMIFS` which as the name suggests, will let you define multiple criterias, like this:

`=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,"Fruits",B2:B7,"Orange")`
This will return 30.

`=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,"Vegetables",B2:B7,"Orange")`
And this will say 14.

So the **first argument** is the area where the **numbers to be summed** are;
**Next** you will add **the range** where you would like to evaluate the **following, the criteria**.

**Edit**

I see that you might want to use `COUNTIFS` to return the number of occurences, not the total, in this case, this might be very similar:

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"Fruits",B2:B7,"Orange")`

Comment: Don't I need C2:C7 in Countifs? How does it figure out from which column does it need to pick up the data?

Comment: I think you can look at it like an ````AND```` operator, so I'll count all that are fruits and are orange colour. The two ranges with their own criteria will result in what you are looking for. Give it a try, experiment with it, and you will see how it works

Comment: Okay. CountIFs helped me in this case but now I am trying Orange and Green both at the same time. Does this look right? =COUNTIFS(A2:A7,A3,B2:B7,{"Orange", "Green"}). I tried this and it is only considering Orange i.e. I don't get anything for green. I am basically trying to do an OR between Orange and Green.

Comment: Not sure what could be the expected result of that, I mean how would excel know which one to choose? If you just try to create one formula, that dynamically adjusts to the column label (A3 and A4 in your example), then you could do ````=COUNTIFS(Data!$A$2:$A$7,A3,Data!$B$2:$B$7,"Orange")```` when you pull this down, it should adjust to the nth row, while preserving the lookups

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to work with your original formula if

(1) You put extra brackets as shown

(2) Use SUM instead of COUNT

(3) Enter it as an array formula using Ctrl-Shift-Enter

```
=SUM(IF((Data!$A$2:Data!$A$7=A3) * (Data!$B$2:Data!$B$7="Orange"),Data!$C$2:Data!$C$7))
```

so it appears with curly brackets round it.

I also had to re-type the quotation marks to get it to work.

```
=SUM((Data!$A$2:Data!$A$7=A3) * (Data!$B$2:Data!$B$7="Orange") * Data!$C$2:Data!$C$7)
```

is another way of doing it, also as an array formula.